# What is the angular momentum of a double pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames

Is there a specific formula to calculate the angular momentum of a double pendulum?

Comment: Would it be ok to write the generalized angular momentum?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the definition of Angular momentum which is $L=r\times{p}$.

Since [Double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) is a system that doesn't not have exact analytic solution for the equation of motion, there is no direct explicit formula to calculate the Angular Momentum, instead you have to find $mr\times{v}$ after finding $v$ and $r$ by solving the coupled equations of motion